# Trying to use float() in column_property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to convert a column into a float while assigning a column using column_property:

```
class voteinfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'voteinfo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    upvotes = Column(Integer)
    downvotes = Column(Integer)
    controversial = column_property(float(upvotes - downvotes)/(abs(upvotes + downvotes)+1)

    def __init__(self, upvotes, downvotes):
        self.upvotes = upvotes
        self.downvotes = downvotes
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm using column_property because I want to be able to sort by controversial.

Answer (score 3):

From the [sqlalchemy docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#alternatives-to-column-property), the best way to do this is to define a python `@property`. You also need to use the built-in sqlalchemy float type.

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Float

class voteinfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'voteinfo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    upvotes = Column(Integer)
    downvotes = Column(Integer)

    @property
    def controversial(self):
        return Float(self.upvotes - self.downvotes)/Float(abs(self.upvotes + self.downvotes)+1)


    def __init__(self, upvotes, downvotes):
        self.upvotes = upvotes
        self.downvotes = downvotes
```

Comment: It doens't work. I have to use Python's float type and use self.upvotes and self.downvotes.

Comment: adding "self." to your class-level variable declarations isn't valid python

Comment: yeah, but for some reason I need to do it with SQLAlchemy